# Service and activity communication, method update in all activities

Tags: android, service

In first Activity I've started this service:

```
    public class TaskMsg extends Service
{       
    private static Timer timer; 
    private Context ctx;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
          return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() 
    {
          super.onCreate();
          timer = new Timer();
          ctx = this; 
          startService();
    }

    private void startService()
    {           
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 35000);
    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);                       
        }
    }    

    public void onDestroy() 
    {   
        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();          
    }

    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            // for example, 2*3;
        }
    }
}
```

In handleMessage method where I have a few operation. It's working fine. 
But I have problem, because I would like to call to activity (from this Service) that in service has new result operation. In all Activity in my project, I have method Update. I need only information that Handler in Service returned new information to all Activity or current Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use a custom broadcast receiver. From the service you can broadcast the message and can write a receiver in your activity. In onReceive() in your activity, you can call to your update() method.

Hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Thank You! Is it good solution for few activities?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.UPDATE);        
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    intent = new Intent(Activity2.UPDATE);        
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    intent = new Intent(Activity3.UPDATE);        
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```